# Kept getting socket connection timeout exception

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, connection

In my Java code, I tried to access a url. I kept getting socket connection timeout exception, no matter how I set the timeout. It seems the Java connection timeout value cannot be increased.

But I can browse that URL in web browser.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: def url = new URL("https://xxxxxxx");
def connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 1000);
connection.connect();

Comment: Isn't it simply your firewall who is blocking HTTP requests from Java?

Comment: Your browser is probably using a proxy while your Java process tries a direct connection.

Comment: no. I didn't configure any proxy for my web browser.

Comment: @willpowerforever: can you try an internal/intranet url or localhost if you have a server running on your desktop?

Comment: I can connect to any URLs except the url I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what it says in the Javadoc. the socket connect timeout cannot be increased beyond the platform default, which is of the order of a minute.

Comment: Hi, EJP. You came out!!! I know you were encountered such issue. So, how did you handle it?

Comment: You can't handle it. You can just keep retrying. But if you can't connect in about ten seconds you will never be able to connect, let alone a minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you see connect timeout, it is possible that firewall is blocking the access.

Comment: It cannot mean nobody was listening on the port. That causes 'connection refused'. It can mean a firewall, or a genuine network connectivity problem.

Comment: EJP, yes I was wrong, it do not mean server is not listening on the port. Let me correct my response.